# Conditional type based on the variable

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I want be able to choose the right type from something like "type map" by passing some variable to component props. I'd call it "Conditional types", but I did't find a solution on the corresponding page of the documentation for typescript.

Here is a simplified example:

```
type Queue1 = {};
type Queue2 = {};
type Queue3 = {};
// ... another possible type

type QueueTypes = {
    'Queue1': Queue1,
    'Queue2': Queue2,
    'Queue2': Queue3
    // ...
}

interface Props {
    queueType: keyof QueueTypes;
}

let props: Props = {queue: 'Queue2'}

// Type 'any' cannot be used as an index type
type rightQueueType = QueueType[props.queue]
```

After an hour of googling, I never found the right solution.
Maybe I use typescript in a wrong way somehow?
I'd be happy to have any help.

Link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=23&pln=18&pc=32#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhBBGKBeKBvAvgbgLABQoksCCATGprocdPIhAMxXb4ED0HUAdH4bXD0yEACpCAzq0JRZUAOQNk8gFylGSADQy5ikeVXqK2gnIVLmhi00JYBBAJYA7YBABOAMwCGAY2gAFNwB7MCkMHVkARxFxSDUAawgQII8jMUl2OwJCABsIYCgwYNC1QJCpdAxoxliINT1GAyzBEjcHAHMAC2ALWqpeyQBtIvKeaoQAXSA)

Upd:
I have a reusable generic react component (table) that can work with different types of resources (Queue1, Queue2, etc). I cannot provide the resource type explicitly as it is dynamic. So all I have is a resource type as a string, and I need to somehow convert/cast it to an existing typescript type.
According to my initial playground, it might look something like this:
 /> (React component)

I ended up with this approach (thanks to @jcalz):

```
interface Queue1 { q: 1 }
interface Queue2 { q: 2 }
interface Queue3 { q: 3 }
type QueueTypes = {
    'Queue1': Queue1,
    'Queue2': Queue2,
    'Queue3': Queue3
}

type Props = { [K in keyof QueueTypes]: { queueType: K } }[keyof QueueTypes]
let props: Props = { queueType: 'Queue2' }

// <ResourceTable<QueueTypes[typeof props.queueType]>>
```

Comment: There is no type named `props`, so there's no type named `QueueType[props.queue]`.  I think maybe you want [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFcKYIzIN7ICOAXMrgL4CwAUKJLIihlhAEz5GntW3jTxI0mTAGYOJZGJ5gAngAcmwiABV5EAM7IAvPhrJ9yAOTMch0iYjYANHoPGlrM0Jasb1A0YsinXmjxqyCsgAClAA9nKaOgQA2gDSyKDIANYQMmEwzpiqCuoAuqQEhEo5EKQJ5MjkManpmRal+TQANhBgyHLhkaShEVHiJWqk9i6GVTQBashQwADmABZgDVM6y7kxgRAZHV3qAHTFLKV5QA) but I'm not sure

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do with `rightQueueType`?  I'd hate to write out the above playground link as an answer only to find out that your use case doesn't match it.

Comment: @jcalz I have a reusable generic react component (table) that can work with different types of resources (Queue1, Queue2, etc).
I cannot provide the resource type explicitly as it is dynamic. So all I have is a "resource type" as a string, and I need to somehow convert/cast it to a typecript type.
According to my initial playground, it might look something like this:
`<ResourceTable<QueueTypes[props.queue]> />` (React component)

Comment: @jcalz Looks like your answer helped me. I'm not sure that's the only and only right way to do this, but it works the way I wanted it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Record is an object type whose property keys are K and whose property values are T. That is, keyof Record is equivalent to K, and Record[K] is equivalent to T.

```
type QueueTypes: Record<string, Queue1 | Queue2 | Queue3> = {
    'Queue1': Queue1,
    'Queue2': Queue2,
    'Queue2': Queue3
}
```